# Javascript regular expression: match all characters except a sequence characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have a pattern that can match all characters exclude a sequence characters.

For example: 
I have a string: "An example: campus is not ampious, are also not a camp".
I want to match all except 'amp'. So regex should match:
"An exle: cus is not ious, are also not c".
If I try this pattern: [^(amp)]. It excludes a, m, p, am, amp as well.

My situation is finding a text in html content and highlighted matched texts.
But there some special html characters in html content, such as: \&nbsp\;, \&amp\; etc.
I want to ignore those special html characters when finding.

Pleas help me to find a good pattern.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds exactly backwards; it sounds like you *do* want to match `amp` and just remove all instances of it. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: If I try to do this pattern: 
/[^(amp)]/g
It excludes one of amp.

Comment: in your sample output text are you also looking to drop the `a` right before the word camp?

Comment: Actually my issue to find the text in html content. And highlight the matched text. So it does not a replace behavior.
In html content there some special html character like: &nbsp; &amp;. etc. I want to ignore them

Comment: So just to be clear, your question is vague and inaccurate, and you've shown nothing to demonstrate what you've tried to solve it?

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not show my situation. So my question makes a little confuse :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 text.replace(/amp/g, '')
```

Comment: Actually my issue to find the text in html content. And highlight the matched text. So it does not a replace behavior.
In html content there some special html character like: &nbsp; &amp;. etc. I want to ignore them

Comment: Could you edit your question and have your code example in it?

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: `text.match(/[^,&]/g)` This will give you a list of characters that are not match `,` and `&`. Or `text.split(/[,&]/g)` This will give you a list of string separated by `,` and `&`.